# Memcached open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, memcached

I'm trying to integrate Memcached into my Zend Framework website to speed up Ajax calls, but I'm having trouble. I tried initializing it in my bootstrap with this function:

```
public function _initMemcached(){
    $memcache = new Memcached; 
    $memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211);
    Zend_Registry::set('memcached', $memcache);
}
```

But this simply throws an error that php can't find the class. According to the datacenter hosting my site, Memcached should be installed in `/root/memcached-1.4.13/`, so I tried adding a require_once, and now it's throwing this error:

```
Warning: require_once() [function.require-once]: open_basedir restriction in effect.     File(/root/memcached-1.4.13/Memcached.php) is not within the allowed path(s):
```

I've tried to reset the open_basedir in my bootstrap, but it doesn't seem to be working. How can I get rid of this error so that I can instantiate a memcached object and get on with my business?

EDIT:

The datacenter tells me that memcached.so is inside `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-###/` but I can't access it via SSH to confirm. I have the `extension_dir` in php.ini set to `/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-###/` and I have `extension=memcached.so` but I'm still getting Class not found. Do I have my settings incorrect?

Comment: If you create a script containing `<?php phpinfo() ?>` do you see a section called `memcached` with version and libmemcached version?  If that does not show up, then they have not loaded the memcached extension into PHP.  memcached is not a php script you can include, it is an extension that has to be loaded into PHP via an `extension` directive in `php.ini`

Comment: I already checked that, and it doesn't show up, but they're swearing up and down that they did. The `/root/memcached-1.4.13` folder exists, and it is populated with files, but no php files. I'm not sure if they just halfway installed it or what.

Comment: That's probably where they downloaded it to and compiled it, but the output file should be `memcached.so` which goes into `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-########/` which must then be added to `php.ini` in an extension directive.  If you have shell access, you may have read-only access to the `php.ini` file listed in `phpinfo()`.  If so, try to open the file and see if they even added the extension directive.

Comment: I wasn't able to find memcached.so but I was able to find `libmemcache.so.0` and `libmemcache.so.0.4.0`, what does this mean?

Comment: Those are the library files for libmemcached which is what the PHP extension uses for communicating with memcached servers.  In order to build the PHP memcached extension you need libmemcached which in turn requires libevent.  Its good that those files exist but it still sounds like they haven't actually installed the PHP extension for it.

Comment: According to the datacenter, memcached.so is already in the extensions folder, though I couldn't find it through SSH. I added `extension=memcached.so` to the php.ini file, but I'm still getting class not found when I try to create a memcached object.

Comment: You probably have to give the full path to memcached.so like I referenced above.  /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug..../memcached.so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`memcached` is a php-extension, not a php-script. This means, it must be enabled within `php.ini` with something like

```
extension=/root/memcached-1.4.13/memcached.so
```

or something like that. Find out, how the extension is named.

http://php.net/memcached.setup